# Device Admin and runtime permissions

Tags: android

I am developing an admin app.The app needs also to enable accessabilty service, app usage and a vpn. I was wondering if there is a way to enable only admin app permission and then enable the rest (accesability, app usage and vpn) by code (or any other way so that the user wont know about it), or I have to explicitly ask them all from the user.

Comment: You will not get the access to this methods. There was github project (https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) that allow you to do so, but it is out of date now, and it will not works after publish the app to google play console. Other thing is that your app have to be signed using OS developer keys.

Comment: So i need to ask the approval of the user for all these features (set accesability service, vpn service and app usage statistics) from the user?